# Convert discriminated union (or array of object types) into a mapped type with a literal property as the key

Tags: typescript

Can I convert an `Array<A | B>` **type** into `{ [key: (A | B)['type']]: A | B }` where type `"a"` maps to type `A`, and type `"b"` maps to type `B`.

```
type A = {type: 'a'}
type B = {type: 'b'}

type Kinds = [A, B]
type Kind = Kinds[number]

// How to use the above types to get this?
type ByKind = { a: A, b: B }
```

I want to avoid explicitly declaring each key of the `ByKind` object type, since they are already declared within types `A` and `B`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You were pretty close, we can use a mapped type to map over the union of string literals in `Kind[type]` but we then need to use the `Extract` conditional type to extract the type from the union that fits the key `P`

```
type A = {type: 'a'}
type B = {type: 'b'}

type Kinds = [A, B]
type Kind = Kinds[number]

type ByKind = {
    [P in Kind['type']]: Extract<Kind, { type: P }>
}
```